# ParallelTable Works in Regular Notebook but Gives Error When Packaged

Tags: packages, parallelization

Consider the following:

```
grid = Tuples[Range[0, 3.3083, 0.08468], 3];
k = Length[grid]; vdw = {0.15, 0.19, 0.19, 0.195, 0.195};
PeriodicDistance = 
  Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 2}, {r, _Real}}, 
   Sqrt@Total[((x - y) - 3.3083*Round[(x - y)/3.3083])^2] - r, 
   CompilationTarget :> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Now the following function:

```
Cavs[dat_?MatrixQ] := Module[{pos},
  Do[
   With[{tr = Transpose[dat[[v ;; -1 ;; 5]]]},
    pos[v] = 
     ParallelTable[
      Min[PeriodicDistance[grid[[i]], tr, vdw[[v]]]], {i, k}]
    ],
   {v, 1, 5}];
  pos[2]
  ]
```

with [input file](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=F96524B72DCD75FB&id=F96524B72DCD75FB%2130085)

```
dat = ReadList["filename.ext", {Word, Word} ~ Join ~ Table[Number, {4}]][[All, 4 ;; 6]];

Cavs[dat]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This answer is exactly the same answer I get when I replace `ParallelTable` with `Table`.
Now, if I include this function in a *Mathematica* package I get all sorts of `Part Specification` errors. Here's a sample:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I know `ParallelTable` is the culprit because if I replace it with `Table` in the package it works fine. I just don't know why it works in a normal *Mathematica* notebook session but fails when packaged. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you distributed all needed FN and Var. definitions with `SetSharedFunction `, etc.?

Comment: @rasher, why should that make a difference between running the same code on the notebook vs. being packaged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelTable.html#) carefully, you see why this happens:

> The default value is `DistributedContexts:>$DistributedContexts` with `$DistributedContexts:=$Context`, which distributes definitions of all symbols in the current context, **but does not distribute definitions of symbols from packages**.

Therefore, what you want is (with the addition `DistributedContexts :> Automatic`):

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];

Cavs;

Begin["`Private`"];
grid = Tuples[Range[0, 3.3083, 0.08468], 3];
k = Length[grid]; vdw = {0.15, 0.19, 0.19, 0.195, 0.195};
PeriodicDistance = 
  Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 2}, {r, _Real}}, 
   Sqrt@Total[((x - y) - 3.3083*Round[(x - y)/3.3083])^2] - r, 
   CompilationTarget :> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
Cavs[dat_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{pos}, 
  Do[With[{tr = Transpose[dat[[v ;; -1 ;; 5]]]}, 
    pos[v] = 
     ParallelTable[
      Min[PeriodicDistance[grid[[i]], tr, vdw[[v]]]], {i, k}, 
      DistributedContexts :> Automatic]], {v, 1, 5}];
  pos[2]]

End[];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I remember `ParallelTable` distributes definition automatically, never thought it would be different for packages so I never bothered to check. I guess lesson learned.